Failed to start php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager
After I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04.1, I can no longer start php-fpm8.3, I get the above error, and in the log I have the following:
× php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2024-09-01 20:57:28 EEST; 4min 11s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.3(8)
    Process: 62018 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 68314 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 83 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 62018 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 116ms

Sep 01 20:55:58 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: Starting php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
Sep 01 20:57:28 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep 01 20:57:28 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 01 20:57:28 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: Failed to start php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager.

Sep 01 20:57:28 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit php8.3-fpm.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'.
Sep 01 20:57:28 node.fulgerhost.ro systemd[1]: Failed to start php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit php8.3-fpm.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit php8.3-fpm.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 12158 and the job result is failed.

What should I do to them?

Did you found the solution?

Check this out:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529224/php8-3-fpm-installation-fails-with-post-installation-script-error
