php8.3-fpm installation fails with post-installation script error
I was installing redis and came across php8.3-fpm installation error. This are the relevant installation messages:
apt install redis-server
...
...
Setting up php8.3-fpm (8.3.6-0ubuntu0.24.04.2) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 8.3 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 8.3 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php8.3-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Job for php8.3-fpm.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status php8.3-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xeu php8.3-fpm.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript php8.3-fpm, action "restart" failed.
× php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2024-10-06 13:52:03 CEST; 16ms ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.3(8)
    Process: 285882 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 285889 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 83 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 285882 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 90ms

Oct 06 13:50:33 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: Starting php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
Oct 06 13:52:03 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 06 13:52:03 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 06 13:52:03 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: Failed to start php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager.
dpkg: error processing package php8.3-fpm (--configure):
 installed php8.3-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libjemalloc2:amd64 (5.3.0-2build1) ...
Setting up liblzf1:amd64 (3.6-4) ...
Setting up redis-tools (5:7.0.15-1build2) ...
Setting up redis-server (5:7.0.15-1build2) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/redis.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/redis-server.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.39-0ubuntu8.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php8.3-fpm
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Systemctl and yournalctl messages are not particularly descriptive - just saying php8.3-fpm failed to start with result 'timeout'.
The error seem to be with dpkg processing php8.3-fpm : installed php8.3-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Content of /var/lib/dpkg/info/php8.3-fpm.postinst:
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -e /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper ]; then
    . /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper

    php_enable() {
        # Don't enable PHP FPM by default when Apache 2 is installed
        apache2_msg notice "NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 8.3 FPM by default."
        apache2_msg notice "NOTICE: To enable PHP 8.3 FPM in Apache2 do:"
        apache2_msg notice "NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif"
        apache2_msg notice "NOTICE: a2enconf php8.3-fpm"
        apache2_msg notice "NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed."
        return 1
    }
else
    php_enable() {
        # Don't enable PHP FPM by default when Apache 2 is not installed
        return 1
    }
fi

if [ "$1" = "triggered" ] && [ "$2" = "/etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d" ]; then
    invoke-rc.d php8.3-fpm restart
fi

CONFDIR=/etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d

if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then
    phpini="/etc/php/8.3/fpm/php.ini"

    if [ "fpm" = "cli" ]; then
        ucf /usr/lib/php/8.3/php.ini-production.fpm $phpini
    else
        ucf /usr/lib/php/8.3/php.ini-production $phpini
    fi
    ucfr php8.3-fpm $phpini

    if [ -e /usr/lib/php/php-maintscript-helper ]; then
        . /usr/lib/php/php-maintscript-helper
        
        mods=$(phpquery -M -v 8.3)
        for mod in $mods; do
            php_invoke enmod 8.3 fpm $mod
        done
    fi

    if [ -n "$2" ] && dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt "7.0.3-2~"; then
        rm -f /etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d/20-opcache.ini;
    fi      
fi

# Automatically added by dh_apache2/UNDECLARED
if php_enable; then
        if [ -e /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper ] ; then
                . /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper
                for conf in php8.3-fpm  ; do
                        apache2_invoke enconf $conf  || exit 1
                done
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_systemd_enable/13.14.1ubuntu5
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        # The following line should be removed in trixie or trixie+1
        deb-systemd-helper unmask 'php8.3-fpm.service' >/dev/null || true

        # was-enabled defaults to true, so new installations run enable.
        if deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled 'php8.3-fpm.service'; then
                # Enables the unit on first installation, creates new
                # symlinks on upgrades if the unit file has changed.
                deb-systemd-helper enable 'php8.3-fpm.service' >/dev/null || true
        else
                # Update the statefile to add new symlinks (if any), which need to be
                # cleaned up on purge. Also remove old symlinks.
                deb-systemd-helper update-state 'php8.3-fpm.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installinit/13.14.1ubuntu5
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        if [ -x "$(command -v systemd-tmpfiles)" ]; then
                systemd-tmpfiles ${DPKG_ROOT:+--root="$DPKG_ROOT"} --create php8.3-fpm.conf || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installdeb/13.14.1ubuntu5
dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/init/php8.3-fpm.conf 7.4.3-4\~ php8.3-fpm -- "$@"
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installinit/13.14.1ubuntu5
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        if [ -z "${DPKG_ROOT:-}" ] && [ -x "/etc/init.d/php8.3-fpm" ]; then
                update-rc.d php8.3-fpm defaults >/dev/null
                if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                        _dh_action=restart
                else
                        _dh_action=start
                fi
                invoke-rc.d php8.3-fpm $_dh_action || exit 1
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section


exit 0

Not familiar with how dpkg functions, but exit 1 occurs in 2 locations. First one occurs when reading apache conf files. I have removed apache2 so this one cannot not trigger anymore. The second one just signals that start/restart failed.
Any tips on what could be the problem? This seems to be above my skill level.
Additional info: running systemctl status php8.3-fpm.service returns
× php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2024-10-07 11:34:21 CEST; 1min 33s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.3(8)
    Process: 334032 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 334035 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 83 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 334032 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 98ms

Oct 07 11:32:51 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: Starting php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
Oct 07 11:34:21 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 07 11:34:21 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: php8.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 07 11:34:21 Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base systemd[1]: Failed to start php8.3-fpm.service - The PHP 8.3 FastCGI Process Manager.

Additionaly, manually starting the service with /usr/sbin/php-fpm8.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf returns
NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 334206
NOTICE: ready to handle connections
NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
... no more messages

indicating that fpm was started successfully, but perhaps systemd has an issue? Am I dealing with mismatched PID numbers?

Not too helpful, but the script is exiting at the second exit 1 (initscript php8.3-fpm, action "restart" failed.). The problem is that the service isn't starting due to timeout. I would try and reinstall Apache then sudo apt purge php8.3-fpm; sudo apt install php8.3-fpm and see what happens.

@kos Thank you for commenting. Same error as before.

@Added some more info.

Have you tried killing the lingering fpm instance before retrying to install?

@kos there are no lingering instances after installation fails. But during installation, while it is timeouting: ps aux | grep fpmreturns
sudo apt install php8.3-fpm, sudo apt install php8.3-fpm, apt install php8.3-fpm, /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/php8.3-fpm.postinst configure, /bin/sh /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d php8.3-fpm start, systemctl start php8.3-fpm.service, php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf), php-fpm: pool www, php-fpm: pool www, grep --color=auto fpm

I would try and edit /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf, making sure that a log file is set and set one if it's not, then try and manually start an instance and see if that (hopefully) outputs something to the log file.

@kos Thank you. Found something promising in /var/log/php8.3-fpm.log, not sure how I missed it before: failed to notify status to systemd and then it exits. It appears there is a communcation error between systemd and php8.3-fpm.

Not a real "fix", but see here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1478134#p1478134 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1478399#p1478399 (#1 might be all you need, I don't know, I'm not too familiar with this stuff)

Thanks. Changing type in /lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service is what I ended up doing. I also tried hardcoding PIDfile to the same pid as it is in /etc/php/8.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf, but that didn't work.  Post an answer and I'll accept it.

I did, I'm glad you fixed it :) but I still suggest trying the systemd_interval=0 approach, I've outlined why in my answer. If you decide to give it a try, please let me know if it worked so I can confirm that method as valid in my answer

PHP-FPM is installed as a notify type service; this means that, quoting systemd.service — Service unit configuration:

it is expected that the service sends a "READY=1" notification message via sd_notify(3) or an equivalent call when it has finished starting up

As per this line in your log file:
failed to notify status to systemd

something's up with that; this notification is either never sent or never delivered.
A workaround to get the service to start properly would be to change the service type to exec, by overriding /lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service.
In order to do that, run:
sudo systemctl edit php8.3-fpm

You'll be presented with a commented-out version of the service in an editor (which editor will depend on the environment; by default, on Ubuntu 24.04 it should end up being nano).
Change the file so that it looks like this:
[Service]
Type=exec

Then save the file (in nano: Ctrl + O / Enter / Ctrl + X).
Finally, run:
sudo systemctl restart php8.3-fpm

Note that overriding /lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service (as opposed to manually editing it) is needed because an update of PHP-FPM may very well change /lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service, effectively reverting the change you made.

Thank you. Disabling systemd messages with systemd_interval=0 is not sufficent as systemd still expects them. Changing Type to Exec, or even Simple seems to work.

@sanjihan Right, I don't know what else I was expecting from systemd_interval=0, that probably disables the thing altoghether :| thanks for reporting back! I'll amend my answer

@sanjihan I fully described how to correctly override /lib/systemd/system/php8.3-fpm.service if you're interested

thank you. You saved me a future headache

The root cause of the issue may be the enforced AppArmor profile for php-fpm.
You can make sure if you check system logs (journalctl) and find something like:
Nov 27 08:57:41 ip-10-48-2-196 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1732697859.019:135633): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" class="file" profile="php-fpm" name="/run/systemd/notify" pid=192524 comm="php-fpm8.3" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=0 ouid=0

To fix it just add this line to /etc/apparmor.d/local/php-fpm
owner /run/systemd/notify w,

and restart apparmor service

This is the better answer - the service is designed to work with systemd notify, and it's simply a bug that it can't write to that socket.
